# Splitting a text file on commas and tabs and reordering columns using Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm trying to reorganise some data into a more useful format using Perl. The data currently looks like this:

```
Code             Number
|a,c,2,d,c|        5
|b,d,6,c,b|        2
|d,a,1,b,c|        3
```

The two columns are separated by tabs. However, I would like the numbers in the code column to fall before the letters, so the output looks like this:

```
Code            Number
|2,a,c,d,c|        5
|6,b,d,c,b|        2
|1,d,a,b,c|        3
```

As someone without much experience with Perl, the best way I can think of doing this would be to split the file based on commas into a hash of arrays, then I can reorder the columns so the column containing numbers comes first. Ideally, I would like this to work no matter where the number comes in the code, e.g. if the above output could be achieved for `|a,2,c,d,c|` and `|a,c,2,d,c|` and `|a,c,d,2,c|` too. However, one problem with this is that the different letters and numbers in the 'code' column don't have different headings, which I suspect might be causing me some issues when I attempt to create a hash of the file.

So far, I have this bit of code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'file.txt';
my $output = 'output.txt';

open (my $fh2, '>', $output) or die "Could not open $output $!";
close $fh2;

my %data;
my @datanames;

open ($fh, '<', $file) or die "Could not open $file $!";
open ($fh2, '>>', $output) or die "Could not open $output $!";
while (<$fh>) {
chomp;
my @list=split(/\,/); 
for (my $j=0; $j<=$#list; $j++) {
    if ($.==1) {
        $datanames[$j]=$list[$j];
    }

    else {
        push @{$data{$datanames[$j]}}, $list[$j];
    }
  }
}
foreach (@datanames){
   local $"="\n"; 
   print $fh2 "$_\n@{$data{$_}}\n";
}
close $fh;
close $fh2;

print 'done\n';
```

This gives me a load of uninitialised value errors if I have strict and warnings on, and even if I don't it only prints the headings (code and number), and then for each row, `|` followed by the number value in the `code` column. It looks like this:

```
Code     Number
|2
|6
|1
```

I'm not really sure how to move forwards from this point, or even whether I'm going about solving my problem the right way. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to store anything anywhere. Use [List::MoreUtils](http://p3rl.org/List::MoreUtils)::part to partition the columns based on whether they contain a digit.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use List::MoreUtils qw{ part };

print scalar <>;  # header
while (<>) {
    my @cols = split /\t/;
    my @subcols = split /[,|]/, $cols[0];
    my @parts = part { /[0-9]/ } @subcols[1 .. $#subcols];
    print '|', join ',', @{ $parts[1] }, @{ $parts[0] };
    print "|\t", $cols[1];
}
```